# Kendo Editor : Change event fires only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Error : Kendo Editor : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getSelection' in undefined.
Editor loads and render fine. If I click outside of editor when text value is changed or updated in the editor in change event fires only first time. Second time if I update text and click outside of editor  error is thrown right away. Even though text is updated fine in the editor text area itself, but Js error is thrown as soon as I click outside of editor widget. Change event does not get fire. Select event happens all the time when I click in the text area.
I have tried binding change event even after editor widget is initialized, but can’t get to see change event happens second time. Text area data-bind value is updated through MVVM.
Have tried calling refresh() on change event, that still gives me same error.  If I call refresh on editor select event, it prevents the error, but won't let user type due to focus. Will have to click and hold the mouse down while typing to not lose focus instantly to use refresh method. Calling editor.focus() does not make any difference. Please find below kendo stack trace.

```
kendo.all.js:75062 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getSelection' in undefined
    at Object.selectionFromWindow (kendo.all.js:75062)
    at Object.selectionFromDocument (kendo.all.js:75075)
    at init.getSelection (kendo.all.js:73878)
    at init.getRange (kendo.all.js:73886)
    at init.refreshTools (kendo.all.js:76998)
    at init.value (kendo.all.js:73799)
    at init.refresh (kendo.all.js:9960)
    at init.<anonymous> (kendo.all.js:9070)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:192)
    at init.change (kendo.all.js:8900) 


<div id= "PagePanelBar" data-role="panelbar">
<div class="page-editor"
                 data-bind="visible: TestCheck">
                <textarea data-role="editor"
                          class="editor"
                          id="TestEditor"
                          style="height: 100px;"
                          data-tools="['bold',
                        'italic']"
                           data-bind="value: Text,
                        events: {
                           select: onSelect,
                           change: onChange
                        }">
            </textarea>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't believe this could be it but you have an extra quote next to *italic*

Comment: This is normal that if you have a javascript error, javascript will stop beeing executed and next eventlistener will not be executed

Comment: @CedricCholley: extra quote next to italic was just my typo here. In real code, no extra quotes. JS error is still there.

Comment: I have used your html in the dojo and it works fine (I added my own viewmodel and binding for the MVVM). The change event fires every time without a js error. Are you able to update your question to show your viewmodel with the onSelect and onChange functions because I suspect the problem is there. Or even better a dojo that re-creates the problem.